# Why doesn't the blade on my miter saw spin?

Tags: carpentry

I have a Guild Compound Mitre saw, 1200w. The motor works fine and the blade spins a couple of times (2-3) seconds then stops. I have tried removing the blade and placing back on. I have noticed blade wobbles. I have checked securing nut all good.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this model or brand but either the blade is not properly attached to the motor output shaft or this has a "transmission" or gears or something to transfer rotation of the motor to the blade and that is broken.  The blade should not "wobble", so that's where I'd start looking.

Comment: Either the blade worn/too thin for securing nut or securing nut not tightening the blade enough.  Motor is still turning, but blade stops?

Comment: According to the manual, the outer flange holding the blade on is cupped.  You said blade wobbles, this sounds like outer flange is on backwards.  https://www.argos-support.co.uk/storage/uploads/4598707_R_D001.pdf?direct

Comment: Does the blade stop while the motor continues running?

Comment: You've either installed the blade improperly or something serious is broken. In either case you should not use the miter saw until this problem is resolved unless you want a saw blade lodged in your general chest area.